# Reconstructing / Interpolating underlying timeseries dataset from partial sums

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, probability-distributions, generating-functions

I'm working on a programming problem that has a very interesting mathematical challenge underneath. I'm given a series of sums of data in timeseries, for example:

$20k between 01.01.2022 and 01.03.2022

$16k between 01.04.2022 and 15.05.2022

$12k between 01.02.2022 and 10.04.2022

Now, I want to create a dataset of the MOST LIKELY numbers for each day, given these sums. The assumption is that this data is normally distributed. The resulting dataset has to sum back to the original given sums.

Some images for examples: [Visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEhEn.png)

How would you approach solving this problem?

Comment: How would you approach solving this problem?

Comment: There is no such thing as the most likely number for any given day. If you come up with a set of data following a normal distribution, that satisfies the conditions, any rearrangement of the day values within the three ranges will satisfy the exact same conditions, and be just as likely. So any day within those ranges will be equally likely to fall anywhere within a range. The *expected* value will just be the total for each range divided by the number of days in it. But this will not look "normally distributed".